# What is this Acer motherboard?

Tags: motherboard

I'm trying to upgrade my Acer XC-605.

It seems to have some sort of custom motherboard. The only thing that's present on the board is MS-7869 Ver 1.

Official website doens't have any meaningful manuals.

I'm interested in what some pins mean and whether I can put 8gb sticks in it.

[image]

Comment: Try asking Acer.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to upgrade??? The RAM or ...

Comment: I'm updating the ram and making a custom case for this motherboard. I'm not sure what frontpanel pins are what.

Comment: the big black one at the bottom is GPU slot, those with white tabs are RAM slots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acer SX2885 MS-7869  DBSRRCN001 LGA1150-Motherboard

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).